# Left-to-right Tree in LaTex, not top-to-bottom?

Tags: latex, tree, orientation

I'm looking to draw a tree where the root is on the left and each child node is drawn to the right.

It seems that the `qtree` package can't do this. Any one have any ideas?

I've found [this](http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:ekiOGhdZbEsJ:www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb12-2/tb32swonk.pdf+left+to+right+trees+in+latex&hl=en&gl=uk&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjItHveNWi4z4wvOxEqnh7mLeI2mxYuC1B5BcePdC4m4LMYgS5Ohz5aAdMHdvaBu7OXCi2CuiMHyv2vppddPqkxvOgIG-K8xlSdIObYthpkUe0Ggg7bTgvDc1bFdtOFdOot1NTv&sig=AHIEtbQiYcvEDVEv_EH1-27joIBHOSXG9A) document, which seems like it might help, but it's a bit obtuse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at **[TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) [trees](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/)**, it can be done here, by setting the parameter `grow=right`.

For example:

http://media.texample.net/tikz/examples/PNG/probability-tree.png

[Taken from the TikZ website]

Comment: @billy Thank the maintainers and contributors of the TikZ package. This package dwarfs every other contribution to LaTeX.